# Attribute name must contain word characters only

Tags: forms, yii2, gii

I'm creating a profile form using gii and after doing the gii part and when I open the page for creating the form and I click on the "Creating Profile" it shows up with this error:

Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
Attribute name must contain word characters only.

and this is the photo of the associated table in the db.
[phpmyadmin table view](http://uupload.ir/files/alc6_screenshot_from_2016-04-06_00-14-29.png)

if you needed anymore informations just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your table You have

```
 father-s_name
```

the `-` is not allowed in yii2 field naming convention

use

```
 father_s_name  or fathers_name
```

Answer (score 0):

for example your column name is **İmage_name** *capital letter(İ)* you may take such error. You must change with *lowercase letter(i)*, for example: **image_name**